# Volume of $\{(x,y,z): \left \|A\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix} \right \| _{1} <1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

$M_1=\{(x,y,z)^T \in \mathbb R^3: |x|+|y|+|z|<1\}$

I evaluated the volume of $M_1$: $\lambda_3(M_1)=\frac{4}{3}$

Now consider

$M_2=\{(x,y,z)^T \in \mathbb R^3:|a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}z|+|a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}z|+|a_{31}x+a_{32}y+a_{33}z|< 1, ~ a_{i,j} \in \mathbb R \} $

How can I evaluate $\lambda_3(M_2)$ using $\lambda_3(M_1)?$

I am not sure if I need to multiply or divide by $\det A$.

Comment: $M_2 = A^{-1}M_1$. Do you know the integral transformation formula (generalization of change of variable)?

Comment: $\lambda_d(T(B))=\int_B |det dT(x)|d\lambda_d(x)$. So using $M_2=A^{-1}M_1$ we have $\lambda_3(M_2)=\frac{1}{\det A}\lambda_3(M_1)$.

The thing that is confusing me is $M_2=A^{-1}M_1$, I thought it is $M_2=AM_1$

Comment: You forgot the absolute value around the determinant. And yes, $M_2 = A^{-1}M_1$ because $M_2 = \{v : \|Av\|=1\} = \{A^{-1}w : \|AA^{-1}w\|=1\} = A^{-1}\{w : \|w\|=1\} = A^{-1}M_1$. So, the answer is $\frac{4}{3|\det A|}$.